# create a visualization to show the time period

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this. I would like to create a visualization to show the time period when each of the ID was active and for how long it was active. So essentially time on the x axis and ID on the y axis and create horizontal bars with barwidth corresponding the duration.

```
mydata <- data.frame(start_time=c(as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 02:07:27", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 06:10:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-07 03:27:30", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-07 08:12:54", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 02:07:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 16:08:27", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-03 02:08:22", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-04 02:08:15", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-05 21:10:48", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                         as.POSIXct("2015-01-06 09:10:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
                     end_time=c(as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 02:08:27", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 06:12:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-07 03:29:30", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-07 08:15:11", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-02 16:07:21", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-03 02:07:02", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-04 02:07:06", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-05 20:07:54", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-06 09:07:35", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-06 20:08:36", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
                     ID=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"))
```

My question is how do I create a x axis that is suitable for my purpose. Any guidance/comments would be appreciated. What I need is something like below

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = time(?), y = ID)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = end_time, xmin = start_time)) + # the width of bar
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```r
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = start_time, y = ID)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = end_time, xmin = start_time), height = 0.5) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%b-%y")
```

[image]

A more involved, but perhaps easier-to interpret method would involve adding some rectangles to show the different periods explicitly:

```r
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = start_time)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmax = end_time, 
                xmin = start_time,
                ymax = as.numeric(factor(ID)) + 0.25,
                ymin = as.numeric(factor(ID)) - 0.25,
                fill = factor(seq(nrow(mydata))))) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = start_time, xmax = end_time, 
                     y = as.numeric(factor(ID))), height = 0.25) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%b-%y", name = 'Date') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2), labels = levels(factor(mydata$ID)),
                     name = 'ID') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]